# node loses connection to testrpc

Tags: testrpc, nodejs

Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) on writing a voting contract and deploying on testrpc I created the below js code into `voting.js` and ran it by:

```
> node
> require('./voting.js');
```

After printing `web3.isConnected()` in some places it seems that after requiring the solc package the connection looses. Any idea why? how to solve?

voting.js:

```
Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
console.log(web3.isConnected());

fs = require('fs');
console.log(web3.isConnected());
code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString();
console.log(web3.isConnected());

solc = require('solc');
console.log(web3.isConnected());
compiledCode = solc.compile(code);

console.log(web3.isConnected());

abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts['Voting'].interface);
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts['Voting'].bytecode;

console.log(web3.isConnected());
VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition);
console.log(web3.isConnected());
deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000});
console.log(deployedContract.address);
contractInstance = VotingContract.at(deployedContract.address);

contractInstance.totalVotesFor.call('Rama');
```

The output:

```
> node
> require('./voting.js');
[ '0xabefa5873fe5c980a2b7ffe84a6726386a1c6c3a',
  '0xe4bf2c9df073808c187066adac463f2b2a4a3847',
  '0x49d61cad7ad214f968a4d5b402e936aa3eef1ef5',
  '0xbb3ae1453c1c843f28952611c3948691376003bc',
  '0xb57b5c0f2ec7869c2371831c11a4d1f8c54086bb',
  '0xb14fad57e7ab17d378499e8aa0f2bbefa9f70344',
  '0xc911f8c0f1d2e2e4a08d0c5eaf3390d54cb6ce93',
  '0x6ee5769268c665f0c9541ecd0216041af111dced',
  '0x79a88a34d78151d9d79b997b51f14ea4211faacd',
  '0x8a287c6e4407ed53723cc9cde6741125efdbc8ba' ]
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545.
    at Object.InvalidConnection (/home/bush/hello_world_voting/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:31:16)
    at HttpProvider.send (/home/bush/hello_world_voting/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:83:22)
    at RequestManager.send (/home/bush/hello_world_voting/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:32)
    at Eth.get [as accounts] (/home/bush/hello_world_voting/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/property.js:107:62)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bush/hello_world_voting/voting.js:24:93)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that requiring 'solc' causes the connection to TestRPC to drop. I have not investigated why, but a workaround is to avoid requiring 'solc' in your current node console session by compiling the contract and writing it to a file before starting your console session.

Run `compile.js` at the command line with: `~$ node compile.js` before requiring `voting.js` in your node console.

File contents:

compile.js

```
solc = require('solc');
fs = require('fs');

code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString();
compiledCode = solc.compile(code);
fs.writeFileSync("./Voting.compiled", JSON.stringify(compiledCode), 'utf-8');
```

voting.js

```
Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);

compiledCode = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./Voting.compiled").toString());

abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface);
VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition);
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].bytecode;

deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama', 'Nick', 'Jose'], 
        {   data: byteCode,
            from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
             gas: 4700000,
        });



setTimeout(
    function(){
        console.log(deployedContract.address);
        contractInstance = VotingContract.at(deployedContract.address);
        console.log(contractInstance.address);
        console.log(contractInstance.totalVotesFor.call('Rama'));
}, 3000);
```

Note: You have to wait for `VotingContract.new` to return before you can set `contractInstance`, or else it will be undefined. I therefore wrap it in a `setTimeout` that waits three seconds, plenty of time for `VotingContract` to return after submitting the contract to your TestRPC server. This is not usually best practice for dealing with asynchronous functions, but satisfies the requirements for the demo with the minimal amount of rewriting and additional packages.

Comment: Why did you put ':' before Voting in `compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface`? (it throws an exception that it doesn't know such object. Also - missing `fs = require("fs");` at the beginning of voting.js